# How to squash Liquibase files to reflect current database state

Tags: sql-server, version-control, liquibase

We're using Liquibase at our company for version controlling the SQL Server database tables, stored procedures etc. What we have been doing to far is write the changes to a SQL file and then mention the file path in `DbChangeLog.xml` file. For example, if I have a stored procedure `X`, and I want to make some changes to it, I create a SQL file which contains the `ALTER PROCEDURE X...`. The previous version of stored procedure `X` is also written to another file. The the files are then mentioned in the `DbChangeLog.xml` as follows:

```
<changeSet author="<author>" id="<id>">
    <sqlFile endDelimiter="\nGO" path="ChangeSetScripts/alter_procedure_X.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" splitStatements="true" stripComments="false" />
    <rollback>
      <sqlFile path="ChangeSetScripts/alter_procedure_X_rollback.sql" />
    </rollback>
  </changeSet>
```

Over time the `DbChangeLog.xml` file has grown and now the `ChangeSetScripts/` folder contains almost 1500 files! I would like to know if there is any way to **squash** all the changes to a single file and use that file instead of maintaining a large number of files as we're doing now. I can think of solution like this: Export the script from SQL Server that generates all the tables, types and stored procedures and use that SQL file. Is this an acceptable solution or are there any best practices that I should go forward instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can use two liquibase commands in this case.

1. [generateChangeLog](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html) command: This command will capture everything from your database into one file
2. [changeLogSync](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/changelogsync.html?Highlight=changelogsync) command - It will sync all the changesets generated from generateChangeLog command and update as already deployed.

Effectively these operations are going to squash all the files into single file.